Find the ray($x)$ of the quadrant below
In the figure if $AO = OB = x$, $AQ = 3$ and $BP = 4$.
Calculate "$x$", where $MN^2 = AM^2+BN^2$
(Answer:5)

I try:
$BP^2 = BN.BO = BP.x = 16$
$AQ^2 = AM.x = 9$
$ \therefore \frac{16}{BP} =\frac{9}{AM}$
$\triangle OPB: x^2 = BP^2+OP^2 \implies (\frac{16}{BP})^2= BP^2+OP^2$

Since
$ON=x-BN$
$OM-x-AM$
$MN^2=AM^2+BN^2$ , (given)
$MN^2=ON^2+OM^2=(x-BN)^2+(x-AM)^2=2x^2-2BNx-2AMx+AM^2+BN^2$(pytha)
then
$MN^2=2x^2-2BNx-2AMx+MN^2$
$x^2-BNx-AMx=x(x-BN-AM)=0$,$x=0$(NA) or $x=AM+BN$
$BP^2= 4^2=16=x\times BN$ ,(power of a point)
$AQ^2= 3^2=9=x\times AM$ ,(power of a point)
$9+16=25=x\times AM+x\times BN=x\times(AM+BN)=x^2$
$x=5$ or $x=-5$ (NA)

Very good...thanks for help

This answer uses the same elements as Lion Heart, but a different strategy:
From the Pythagorean theorem we have $$NM^2=OM^2+ON^2=AM^2+BN^2$$
From the powers of $A,B$:
$$AQ^2=9=AO(AM)=x(AM)\\
BP^2=16=BO(BN)=x(BN)\\
\Rightarrow 25=x(AM+BN)$$
But also
$$25=AM(AO)+BN(BO)\\= AM(AM+MO)+ BN(BN+NO)\\=AM^2+BN^2+AM(MO)+BN(NO)\\=OM^2+ON^2+AM(MO)+BN(NO)\\=OM(OM+AM)+ON(ON+BN)\\=x(OM+ON)$$
Thus $$25=x(AM+BN)=x(OM+ON)\\ \Rightarrow AM+BN=OM+ON$$
But this means we have both:
$$AM^2+BN^2=OM^2+ON^2\\AM+BN=OM+ON$$
If we substitute dummy variables for ease of manipulation we have $a+b=c+d$ and $a^2+b^2=c^2+d^2$, implying $ab=cd$ and $a=c,b=d$ (or vice versa), so, returning to our original expressions of power: $$9=a(a+b)\\16=b(b+a)\\25=a^2+ab+b^2+ab\\ 25=(a+b)^2 \\5=a+b$$

Thanks for help
